# Not able to compile glib program

Tags: glib

I am compiling my first `glib` program and I am getting the error as

```
first.c:2:19: fatal error: gtypes.h: No such file or directory
```

compilation terminated.

I am compiling using pkg-config utilit as mentioned in GLib manual
Here is output of `pkg-config --cflags glib-2.0`

```
==>-I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include
```

And the command I am using for compiling is

```
gcc `pkg-config --cflags glib-2.0` first.c
```

What could be the reason ?

Comment: Are you using `#include <gtypes.h>`?

Comment: yes I was using the gtypes.h

Comment: Don't. Always include glib.h only.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your include to

```
#include <glib/gtypes.h>
```

and you'll see an error saying not to include `gtypes.h` directly. Your pkg-config usage looks good, so use this instead,

```
#include <glib.h>
```

and it should include `gtypes.h` and other headers necessary for `glib`.

Answer (score 0):

GLib, like many other libraries in the G* stack, ship with multiple header files, but only allow inclusion of a top-level header file from user code. This is meant to avoid dependency issues when including headers, as well as allow the library developers to move definitions and symbols around without breaking user code.

For GLib, the top-level headers that you can include are, in order of complexity:

- `glib.h`, for the low level types and API
- `glib-object.h`, the the GType type system
- `gio/gio.h`, for the GIO input/output and high level API (e.g. GDBus, GSettings, etc.)

Each header after `glib.h` includes the previous ones as well, so you don't need to include `glib.h` if you want to use GObject, and you don't need to include `glib-object.h` if you wish to use GIO.